# Are Bitnami Stacks Efficient?

Tags: vps, bitnami

I currently have a server running Cherokee, but I've had many issues with my software wanting particular technology from other servers (mostly Apache) and I was thinking of switching to Bitnami stacks since I have some diverse software (Wordpress, Django, Rails).

My VPS has only 728mb ram though, I was worried that bitnami stacks may not make efficient use of my available ram. Does anyone know if that's an issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a BitNami developer I can tell you that in general the BitNami Stacks are prepared to work on systems with low resources. Apart of the users that use BitNami in production environment, we also found lot of users that just want to give a try to a specific application in their local environment. This environment is not always a huge machine. For instance sometime ago we made BitNami Alfresco Stack (a java application which consume lot of resources on Windows) work in machines with only 512M RAM.

Comment: Interesting... thank you for the response! Love BitNami stacks!

Comment: I enjoy using Bitnami as well.

Comment: Same here, I appreciate Bitnami stacks and think highly of the company.